# MySQL insert query inserting more than one record at a time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I am having following piece of code in my project:

```
$start_time = $this->input->post("start_time");
$a          = explode(":",$start_time);
$start_sec  = ($a[0]*3600)+($a[1]*60);
$end_sec    = $start_sec+5400;
$m          = ($end_sec/60);
$hrs        = (int)($m/60);
$mins       = ($m%60);
$sec        = "00";
$end_time   = $hrs.":".$mins.":".$sec;
$start_time .= ":".$sec;


$tablearr=array(
  "rest_id"        => $info['rest_id'],
  "rest_sec_id"    => $info['rest_sec_id'],
  "book_date"      => $this->input->post("date"),
  "book_start_time"=> $this->input->post("start_time"),
  "book_end_time"  => $end_time,
  "book_special"   => $this->input->post("purpose"),
  "book_cuisine"   => $this->input->post("cuisine"),
  "book_no_person" => $this->input->post("no_person"),
  "user_id"        => $this->session->userdata('member_id'),
  "book_is_menu"   => $this->input->post("menu"),
  "table_reserved" => $info['table_reserved']
);

$this->db->insert("b_rest_book",$tablearr);
```

This should insert single record of "Booking". But insted the query inserting 5 records on execution: One record with all correct values and rest 4 records with null values.

The start time is entered by user and end time is calculated based on start time.

And after inserting the table Looks something like this :

```
book_id     rest_id     rest_sec_id     book_date   book_start_time     book_end_time   book_special    book_cuisine    book_no_person  user_id     book_is_menu    table_reserved  special_request

1   1   2   2012-12-23  07:00:00    08:30:00    2   2   2   2   No  1 

2   1   0   0000-00-00  00:00:00    01:30:00    0   0   0   2       1 

3   1   0   0000-00-00  00:00:00    01:30:00    0   0   0   2       1 

4   1   0   0000-00-00  00:00:00    01:30:00    0   0   0   2       1    
5   1   0   0000-00-00  00:00:00    01:30:00    0   0   0
```

What exactly going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($info['rest_sec_id'] != 0)
{
   $this->db->insert("b_rest_book",$tablearr);
}
```

Comment: Nicely spoted.. but i didn't get it.. there is no loop here..?

Comment: @senk - iam just giving this solution. but i don't know codeignter